# Line 12 of 1020-S Sub-S Corp return

Tags: united-states, income-tax, s-corporation

My accountant has fallen seriously ill, I'm sole owner and employee of a Sub-S Corp.
I'm looking at my 2018 Corp Tax return at line 12, trying to figure out what I should enter there for the 2019 return.

I saw this question, but I'm still stuck: [Clarification on line 12 of US tax form 1120S for S Corporations](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/106706/clarification-on-line-12-of-us-tax-form-1120s-for-s-corporations)

How can I find how he computed Line 12.  Would the calculation be available from my W2?

And of course I have the check register, with all the payments to the IRS for the withholding.

I have tried to construct the payroll numbers from emails he sent me over that year.
For most the payrolls, I have sort of a stub he created that shows the Fed Withholding, the Social Sec, and Medicare, and "Regular Pay", and "Net Pay".

On this site, I found the following quote:
https://evergreensmallbusiness.com/quick-and-dirty-payroll-for-one-person-s-corps/

> Your corporation pays a 7.65% Social Security and Medicare payroll
> tax. If your S corporation pays you payroll of $10,000 a quarter, that
> amount equals $765 obviously.

Should I be able to compute that number given any or all of the above? If so, how?